# asterisk in front of class name at the top

Tags: java, eclipse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wq13.png)

even though the code has no errors I'm not getting any output, instead the console is showing output for a different code. And there's some asterisk in front of class name at the top.

Comment: take a screenshot of whole window screen.

Comment: uploaded the full screenshot, can you help now...?

Comment: Did you save the file?

Comment: No. Please don't post images. At least not until you have a clear question. What is your actual question? Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You want to search on "eclipse run configurations"

Comment: the asterisk means that the file was changed and not saved - also implies that the changes were not compiled - CTRL-SHIFT-S or "save all"

Answer (score 0):

First, it's better you define a new class and surround these two classes in one 
[image]

Be sure when u mouse over the run icon it shows the name of yr class:
[image]

by the way, you should see an error in the editor:

```
No enclosing instance of type RunnableThreadTest is accessible. 
Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type RunnableThreadTest (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of RunnableThreadTest).
```

you need to make RunnableThread class to static

```
public class RunnableThreadTest {
    public static class  RunnableThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("gothu");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        RunnableThread r = new RunnableThread();
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the run configuration that you are using, maybe you had run a configuration of another main file.

The asterisk in front of file name means that the file is unsaved. Save it and the asterisk will disappear.